# Adding a command to the right-click menu of the file explorer in python

Tags: python, tkinter, contextmenu

`MyScript.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys

root = Tk()

def open_file(file_to_open):
    if file_to_open != "":
        file = open(file_to_open , 'r')
        text.delete('1.0' , END)
        text.insert('1.0' , file.read())
        file.close()

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

open_button = Button(root , text = "Open" , command = lambda: open_file(filedialog.askopenfilename()))
open_button.pack()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    open_file(sys.argv[1])

mainloop()
```

`launcher.bat`:

```
@echo off
python MyScript.py %1
```

Here, I would like to add a command/sub-menu to the right click menu of the windows explorer, and whenever that sub-menu is clicked, I would like to run the `launcher.bat` file.

I mean, I want to add a command like this to the right click menu:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this in python?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: "_Is there any way to achieve this in python?_" I think this is out of pythons hand

Comment: Read: [One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers?redirectedfrom=MSDN#cascade_subcommands) and [Two](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3ee4702a-f75a-4790-9332-e50f241efd6f/unable-to-create-extended-cascaded-menu-using-extendedsubcommandskey?forum=windowsuidevelopment)

Comment: Try right clicking on the file, click on `Open with`, click on `Choose another app`, click on `More apps`, click on `Look for another app on this PC` (at the bottom), Navigate and choose your `launcher.bat` file. That should work on Windows 10

Comment: @TheLizzard: I am aware of that way, but it would be a long work for the user. I want the command to appear on the right click menu so that the user can easily open my app.

Comment: @Lenovo360 it should then always open with that application (I think) so you only have to do that once

Comment: @TheLizzard: Yes, the file will always open in my script if I do that, but what if the user only want's to open the file in my app sometimes?

Comment: @CoolCloud: I have gone through the docs you have provided, but I am looking for a way to do this with a python script, as I can immediately add the command to the right click menu when the user installs my app.

Comment: [Take a look](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) at the **winreg** modul. An exampel can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jS2LuG1p8Vw).